# What is the correct way to call a validation Jscript function when there is a DB call?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, database, validation

Sorry if the title doesn't explain much.

I have a page with a textbox, a button and an error message.

I need to validate if the text entered in my textbox is not null or empty, has good length, that there is no weird characters in it and last but not least, that the username doesn't already exists in my Database. That part is done and working.

My question is, what's the best way to call my Jscript function that validate the asp:textbox where the username is type.

Right now I see 3 different ways.

1. Using .blur to call it when focus is lost on the textbox
2. Using .keyup or .keydown to call it whenever a key is pressed
3. Using a timer to validate every X seconds

Now the problem with .blur is that it doesn't validate without loosing focus on the only thing worth of focus on the page. Problem with .keyup and .keydown is it will call my DB way too many times. And the problem with the timer is I'm not exactly sure if there is a problem with the timer, which is why I'm asking.

I also have a validation server side so it cannot go throught.

For more information, here the jscript with the .blur I have right now.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Name;
var NameValid = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    Name = $("#txtBox");
    validateName();
    Name.blur(function () {
        validateName();
    });

});

function validateName() {
    NameValid = false;
    PageMethods.NameValidMethod(Name.val(), successName, error);
};
```

What would be the best way to do it?

Edit: To add more information. Right now my page is only a textbox and a button. In the future when I get to update my website I'll have more then a textbox in the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For short forms, the best user experience is to perform validation upon the submission of the form.  Are you completely opposed to having a button and/or relying on the user to hit the 'enter' key?

Then the following validation would be done with Javascript on the submission of the form: "if the text entered in my textbox is not null or empty, has good length, that there is no weird characters in it"

Then if all of those pass, you would continue the submission to the server to check the uniqueness of the username.

Comment: The thing is, I'd rather prefer the user not having to press any button and not using enter key to validate. I want to disable my submit button as long as the name isn't valid. But now that I think about it I realise it's not really doable with a call to DB. So my guess is I should put a "Check availability" next to my textbox to validate it as well as use the .blur or .change

Comment: This compromise seems fair.  I recommend doing the first steps of validation with Javascript as you suggest on blur or change, and then only going to the DB for uniqueness check on click of your newly added button.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm gonna do. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at `.submit()` function? It called just before you submit the form and is genearaly the case for validating forms:

You can call like this:

```
$('form').on('submit',function(data){
    //Validate the users info.
    //if not valid call e.preventDefault();
});
```

API: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

If you want to go on the road of validate each field ( Enjoying IMO) you can use the the `change()` jquery function which is called when something changes:

```
$('input..').on('change',function(){
    //That input has changed, validate it now.
});
```

API: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: .change will get the same result as .blur (on focus lost) while for submit, see my comment on JacobMcLock answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my suggest ion you choose right way to dealing with client-side validation.  Validation based on times does not seems be good idea and it’s also not very practical.

Comment: That's what I told myself about a timer.